# I am having trouble placing a div in a random position

Tags: javascript

I am trying to randomly place a div, but I am getting a type error. It says the element is undefined, but I thought that I was defining it with the const line of line 1. In my CSS file, the position of the div is absolute and there's a background image set. I can tell in the console.log that I am getting the random numbers that I want. I am just having a little trouble attaching those coordinates to the div.

```
const animal = document.querySelectorAll('.animal');

function getRandomPos(animal) {
    var x = screen.width;
    var y = screen.height;
    var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
    var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * y);
    console.log(randomX, randomY);

    let rect = animal.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);

    animal.style.left = randomX;
    animal.style.top = randomY;
}
```

Comment: as you are using `querySelectorAll` this results in `animal` being a HTMLCollection, not a single element. a HTMLCollection does not have `style` property for example ... try using `querySelector` instead

Comment: change `querySelectorAll` to `querySelector` if you have only one element. if you more than one then you need to loop through each one...

Comment: Are you sure the first line, where `animal` is defined, is actually executed *after* the HTML has been parsed? If it is read early on during page load (or not at all) the constant will be `undefined`

Comment: I used querySelectorAll because in the end, there will be several divs doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major issue was already addressed in the comments - querySelectorAll returns an HTMLCollection rather than a single element, so you'll need querySelector.
Also, you'll need to add "px" units to the lines where you're setting the element's style (see below).

**UPDATE**

Questioner mentioned having multiple randomly moving elements, so I've added an example that includes how that might be done using IDs as an argument to the setRandomPos function.

```js
function setRandomPos(target) {
  const element = document.getElementById(target);
  // var x = screen.width;
  var x = 400; // Just smaller numbers for the example
  // var y = screen.height;
  var y = 200;
  var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
  var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * y);

  // Remember to add px for units
  element.style.left = randomX + 'px';
  element.style.top = randomY + 'px';
}
```

```css
.randMove {
  position: fixed;
}

button {
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="animal" class="randMove">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e7/Animal_%28Muppet%29.jpg/220px-Animal_%28Muppet%29.jpg" alt="Animal">
</div>

<div id="grover" class="randMove">
  <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/muppet/images/f/f7/GroverFullFigure2.png/revision/latest?cb=20190222025220" alt="Grover">
</div>

<button onClick="setRandomPos('animal')">Move Animal</button>
<button onClick="setRandomPos('grover')">Move Grover</button>
```

Comment: I think one thing that is a challenge for me as a new dev is deciding where I want to put the action. Here, you put the JS on the <img>. I've also seen/used a div with a background-image set. Still there's the possibility of drawing on a canvas element and moving those items. How do you determine what is the best set-up for your project? Here, for instance, I ultimately want to set something up where I have the same action on many items at the same time.

Comment: @user2900299 That's where creative decision making & personal preference comes in. You'll find that there are usually many, many different ways to solve the same problem. When you're starting out, just go with code that makes the most sense to you (you can worry about making it 'elegant' later). To have this work for several elements, you'll want to provide the setRandomPos() function with an argument - setRandomPos(targetID) and then call that function from a button or other interactive element, providing the argument "onclick" - if you want me to add an example of that, let me know.

Comment: Okay. I am curious how you would do this.

Comment: @user2900299 Added it - hope that makes sense. Basically you just provide the JS function with the ID of an element you'd like to move. document.getElementById is then used to target that element and move it.